# Eclipse - Wrong suggestion when extracting a constant with similar variable name

Tags: java, eclipse, constants

I'm using Eclipse Neon in java code,

When I want to Extract Constant for example String value `"subject"` while having a variable name:

```
String subject = "subject";
```

When Extracting Eclipse offers me `SUBJECT2` although I don't have `SUBJECT` constant. It seems to be effected by the existing variable name.

Can I instruct Eclipse to suggest me `SUBJECT` because it's unique?

I didn't find such issue, can this bug be reported to eclipse?

**EDIT**

When extracting `"subject"` from the following it suggest `SUBJECT`

```
p.put("subject", "mySubject");
```

(Different code) When extracting `"subject"` from the following it suggest `SUBJECT2`

```
String subject = null;
p.put("subject", "mySubject");
```

**EDIT 2**

Just adding to @howlger comment, even if subject variable **isn't** *effectively final*, still it suggest `SUBJECT2`:

```
String subject = null;
p.put("subject", "mySubject");
subject = "notFinal";
```

Comment: Why are you trying to extract a constant as a constant in the first place?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it is a string

Comment: Is SUBJECT already in use somewhere in the type hierarchy?

Comment: @nitind There isn't any `SUBJECT`

Comment: You can report bugs at bugs.eclipse.org.

Comment: @nitind just wanted to make sure it's a bug and if there's a workaround (I have many strings to extract)

Comment: Without seeing the code, we can't tell if it's a bug.

Comment: @nitind see my edit, it's a small demo

Comment: Suggesting a constant name identical, other than case, to an existing name may be some kind of anti-pattern.

Comment: @nitind but it's also convention (as extract suggest even) to have UPPERCASE for constant and lowercase for variable

Comment: Eclipse supports both code conventions: a constant name in uppercase that is unique ignoring case to constant, field and variable names. If the local variable `subject` is implicitly final, inline it before extracting `"subject"` to a constant. If `subject` is not implicitly final, the name of the extracted constant should be better something like e. g. `SUBJECT_DEFAULT` instead of `SUBJECT`.

Comment: @howlger thanks for the input, it sounds like an answer, can you write an answer?

Comment: @nitind do you know what category to submit a bug? (I don't find refactor) I think Product:`Platform` and Component `IDE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse suggests a **unique name** for the constant that is not equal ignoring case **to other constants**, but also to other **variables, parameters and fields**. This is done for **code conventions reasons, not only to avoid compiler errors**.

In the given example `String subject = "subject";` there are two cases:

- If `subject` is **implicitly final**, inline `subject` before extracting "subject" to a constant.
- If `subject` is **not implicitly final** because a different value is assigned later: either the name of the extracted **constant should be more specific** (e. g. `SUBJECT_DEFAULT`) **or** the name of the **variable more generic**.

In this case, I like the fact that Eclipse adds a suffix to the name. But there are other cases where, in my opinion, better proposals could be made (which would unfortunately also mean more complexity). Here is an example in which different proposals are made according to where *Extract to constant* is called:

```
public void foo(String subject) {
    System.out.println("subject"); // -> private static final String SUBJECT2 = "subject";
}

public void bar() {
    System.out.println("subject"); // -> private static final String SUBJECT = "subject";
}
```

The issue has already been reported to Eclipse ([further improvements can be reported to Eclipse JDT, to the component *UI* here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=UI)):

- [**Eclipse bug 442071 - [extract constant] constant name suggestion is
  not case sensitive, adds number to suggestion when lowercase variable
  in scope**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442071)

Comment: I found an existing bug from 2014 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442071

Comment: @user7294900 Good finding. I edited the answer accordingly.